# Next-Auth Magic Link Email Sent to Spam

Tags: email, nodemailer, next-auth

So my issue is not neccessarily with next-auth, but perhaps it's a factor.

Like the title says, the verification emails I send to users are almost always inboxed as spam (in Gmail at least).

I checked my email service provider (SES), and I'm looking at it from that side at the moment. But I also wanted to check if there's something I could do server-side to help with this, since it all seems loosy-goosy.

So I was wondering what I could do? Should I try a custom email body? Is there anything from the server side (next-auth) I can do to limit this? Or just focus on seeing what I can change in my email service provider?